# Is there anything wrong with such Rails multi-thread approach?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm fighting with Rails and polling really long jobs (30 minutes and so alike...)
I've read many other options like using BackgroundRb or Background Job, but for now I've tried  something like this :

```
class HeavyController < ApplicationController    

def poll
  render text: $longlog
end

def longjob
  Thread.new do 
    tasks.each do |j|
      # here's the job proc, CPU & IO intense
      $longlog << "some message about current job status"
    end   
  end
end

end
```

on client's side I've wrote simple javascript `setTimeout` that calls repeatedly `$.get('poll_log', {...})` and sets `.html()` of a dialog showing progress.

besides of using Ruby's global `$longlog` (which is obviously wrong), what other problems may arise from this approach ?
Should I leave it for unlocking multithreaded flavour of WEBRick ? But what if WEBRick decides to kill long-lasting task for timeout reasons? May WEBRick in default configuration kill thread from my approach ? 
My application wouldn't be used intensively by the users, definitely not requiring processing thousands of request per second. Rather I need to have opportunity to check status of background job anytime I click "Show status" button on webpage... (Long job may be fired only by admin account)....

Thanks in advance for some directions...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't run anything on Webrick in production, it's only suitable for local testing. Your thread solution will not work if you run multiple instances of your application, it would only work if your next request hits the same instance.

Just put that thing into a background job processor. They are quite easy to set up. BackgroundRb is old and pretty much dead. The choices these days are Sidekiq, Resque, DelayedJob and Backburner. Delayed job is probably the easiest to get started with, since it doesn't require any additional services.

The background job should probably publish it's "log" to the database, something like  `LongjobLog.create(:message => "did stuff")` and then your Javascript poll thing should request items where id > last_received_id to only get the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using gems like DelayedJob works very well. You find the [link](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) helpful. Do you have workers processing your background job? If not that's something you can easily do in the terminal and watch your background job process. I do to see what is actually happening and for understanding what's going on.